# Is it possible to merge/network multiple smartphones and use them as one device?

Tags: networking

I have 4 android smartphones each with 512 gb memory card. Is it possible to somehow combine them together so that I can access a total of 2TB?

My exact use case is to install kmplayer on one of those devices and network/merge the others such that the primary device has access to all the content as if it was on that device itself. I would leave all these phones at home and access the primary device, via some app like splashtop, from the phone that I have on me.

Am aware of cluster/distributed/HPC computing concepts to get many mainframe/workstation/server/home pc systems(and even the raspberry Pi using Beowulf cluster) to work together but in those cases almost all resources are desired to be used unlike my case where I only intend to combine the memory card storage resource.

Comment: What version of Android (and what devices, might be relevant) and is there root access on these devices? Basically you want to do network shares of folders on the devices so that one can access the other 3 devices folders (possible), or you want everything to appear as one single resource (very unlikely)? Curious why something a RP or other device with a network share wouldn't be better, especially since you could VPN it and make it accessible from anywhere...

Comment: @acejavelin I wanted a solution where the total memory of all 3 devices is available as one single memory resource to the primary device. Network shares are possible relatively easily. All the phones are on the latest version of android and high end enough.

Comment: I don't think the Android devices themselves could do this, you would need a third party tool, like a small Linux server to merge the volumes and make it appear as one virtual volume to the other device... Even with root this likely wouldn't be very clean. The Linux instance could be very small, a RPi or a VM would work well.